# Watering Synthetic Grass on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, agriculture, marit-ayin

Is there a problem of watering synthetic grass on Shabbat-

1. If the synthetic grass has gaps or "holes" whereby the water can leak through to the earth underneath it?
2. What if the earth underneath has been covered with some sort of "protective" spray preventing it from growing?
3. If it were permissible to water synthetic grass, would there be any issue of *maarit ayin*? Or is it considered obvious to all that the grass is not real?

Comment: Why does synthetic grass need to be watered?

Comment: maybe it doesn't need to be, but it done by happenstance when a spray system waters the real grass adjacent to the astroturf area

Comment: I realize that the moderators of the site already looked at this question, but it seems too as psak oriented, in that it looks at too many mitigating factors. Each of those 3 points could be separate questions.

Comment: @DoubleAA obviously synthetic grass does not need to be watered. The question is if water happened to fall on it. Such as the case of washing your hands over grass

Comment: @DoubleAA To clean it, for example.